# How would i get this newcommands.index work?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input

What I'm trying to do is get the position of the users input so if they recall a command it will return the value but it doesn't work for some reason idk why I've tried everything I know please help.

```py
#new file
#new untitled file
args = []
newcommands = []
import time,random,os,sys
commands = ["help","version","python"]
while True:
    
    command = input(">")
    if command not in commands:
        print("That command does not exist")
    if command == "help":
        print(commands)
    if command == "version":
        print("Version = 0.0.1")
    if command == "python":
        print("Type exit to exit the python interperter")
        os.system("python")
    if command == "DM ME A COMMAND":
        pass
    if command == "New":
        if len(newcommands) != 5:
         name = input("Enter a name: ")
         text= input("Enter text for the function: ")
         q = newcommands.append(name)
         args.append(text)
        
    if q ==  newcommands.index(0):
         print(args.index(0))
    if q ==  newcommands.index(1):
             print(args.index(1))
    if q ==  newcommands.index(2):
                print(args.index(2))
    if q ==  newcommands.index(3):
             print(args.index(3))
    if q ==  newcommands.index(4):
             print(args.index(4))
    if q ==  newcommands.index(5):
             print(args.index(5))
```

Comment: seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel(at least partially) of [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), or [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I had very badly worded this I really just didnt know how to pull from a list

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what are you trying to do but seems your logic is more than i could understand

because you try to enter New command which is not on the list it means it will never execute the if condition for the "New"

and if that's not all you also try to get [command line args](https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments/) which will never given by the user.

so basically please give the description of you question

Comment: What im trying to do is get a value from a list

Comment: @MissBridgetSavells what i am trying to say is just check out what code is does you use command line argument to get command but after that you use the input to compare just write and if you want to get element from list then list[0], list[1] ....  and so on is applied.

Comment: ``py

if command == newcommands[1]: args[1]
``